# Allowing Excel privileges to SQL server agent

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a SSIS package deployed to SQL 2012. I can run the package if I do a right click and execute, but not if I run it through a SQL Server agent job. The SSIS package makes use of Excel interop to make some changes to the file and then save it. My guess is that SQL Agent account is not allowed to do such operations (Opening the excel application). I have created a proxy for admin and selected the package to be run as that proxy. This also does not work. Anyone knows how to achieve what I want? TYA

Comment: Define does not run. What is the exact error message you are encountering?

Comment: The Job fails. When I try to see the reports for the failed package, I do not see any useful messages. The essence of my question is that I am able to run SSIS package when I run it as the logged in user (Administrator), but it does not run when I run it as SQL agent. How should I enable SQL agent account to have access to open Excel application?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

Create the following folders:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

Explanation:

Microsoft does not recommend to automate Excel or other Office applications via scripts, because *Office applications are designed to be used by a human being, not a machine.*

As a consequence, Excel is expecting a user profile to exist when the application is run. The SQL Server Agent service does not use an existing user profile (even when launched under a proxy user). When Excel is automated and launched via the agent, Excel is looking for that user profile information and the desktop folder.

The agent uses the `systemprofile` folder as its "user" directory.

For some reason, the automated Excel process will fail if the *Desktop* folder does not exist in the *systemprofile* folder. As a consequence, creating a desktop folder for both the 32bits and 64bits system profiles will solve your issue.

Comment: Could you explain how that helps?

Comment: Great! That is really great information, and now the answer makes complete sense. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks for such a deep knowledge! You saved so many hours for our team.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a SSIS Package using a Script Task that made use of Excel Interop; the package would execute in BIDS (as this was executed under my user account), yet when the same package was run as a SQL Agent job step it would throw an error (due to being executed under the SQL Agent account or 'LOCAL SYSTEM').

The error I received for this problem was:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component 
with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
failed due to the following error: 80070005.
```

In order to fix this I created a [Credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190703.aspx) (SSMS > Security > Credentials) for a known user account (best to create a user account with minimal permissions for production purposes).

Then I created a [Proxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190698(v=sql.105).aspx) (SSMS > SQL Server Agent > Proxies > SSIS Package Execution) which was mapped to the credential created above, ensuring that "SQL Server Integration Services Package" is selected under the 'Active to the following subsystems' list.

Finally, open up the properties of the agent job, select 'Steps', edit the step that executes the offending SSIS package and select the proxy that I just created under 'Run as:'.

Answer (score 0):

Does jour SSIs package uses shared folders or something? Sometimes SQL agent is runing under account which has no right to access network (Local System), so that can be problem.

Way to chec if that is problem to set agent to run under your account so if it works you can create new account and give it minimal rights...